# what impact does drop height have on powder segregation?

Tags: design

In the pharmaceutical environment, the drop height from the hopper to the area where it collects must be minimized. Tubes can be used to minimise the height. I know that it affects powder segregation. But do not understand the mechanism of it. How does it affect powder segregation ? As long as the flow is optimal (eg. no bridging), then why will powder still segregate if drop height is not minimal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small powder particles react with the air flow differently, such as small water droplets which never fall and remain suspended in the air and create haze.

So a long shoot will give a chance to the powder to separate.